# Number of triangles with sides in $\{1,\dots,n\}$

Tags: permutations, combinations, triangles, triangle-inequality

Problem: How many triangles can be formed from a set of $6$ rods of length $1,2,3,4,5,6$ cm taken $3$ at a time?

I managed to solve this problem, by applying both the triangle inequalities and testing for solutions (since there were only $15$ valid cases) and found the answer as $7$. But, is there any way I can develop a more general method to solve this problem for a larger number of rods?

It becomes really difficult to sort through individual cases as the number increases, even to $n=9$; I think my answer then was around $90$ or so. So, any suggestions to make my calculation more efficient? or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Why did you say there are only $15$ choices when $\binom{6}{3}=20$? Anyway, for your problem, you can set up a recursion for $f(k):=$ the number of ways using the first $k$ integers. Then $f(k) = f(k-1)+$ the number of ways that include $k$ itself.

Comment: The answer is https://oeis.org/A002623

Comment: Do you allow isosceles triangles? For example, the triangles with length 6, 6 and 5?

Comment: @IvanNeretin It showed that Alfred --- had the answer on no. of non degenerate triangles but the webpage I enter after clicking is empty?

Comment: @LiKwokKeung For the 90 ans, yes but for the original problem, no. I'm trying it without any repetition rn so no isosceles/equilateral triangles allowed

Comment: @BenjaminWang All the cases involving 1 are obviously impossible because then the difference in the lengths of the other chosen sides will always be equal or exceed one, that's why we can easily exclude those cases left with only 15 worth checking. Also, could u please elaborate on the recursion idea? It sounds cool but I have no idea on how to convert it into an explicit form for f(k)